# I am following this amazing youtuber spring boot project ,I want to integrate front end angular login app with this springboot app.How can I do it?

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth-2.0, integration

https://github.com/wdkeyser02/SpringBoot3.1.0-SpringAuthorizationSever1.1.0/tree/part06

I want to change the front end login of this spring boot app with  the angular 13 login app how can I do it .Please suggest steps for integrating angular app with this particular spring boot app and also suggest easy alternative for this problem .